# Laravel 5 - Paypal Payment - Pass data form to controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

i have problem to store forms inputs after the payment paypal.
I have pass the data from form (name, phone_ship, address_ship ecc...) to my function orderSave () So i can store data with the other information. But it doesnt work. 
My variabile $request->get('inputs of form') doesnt exist for function saveOrder

> Argument 1 passed to
>   dixard\Http\Controllers\PaypalController::saveOrder() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\2016\app\Http\Controllers\PaypalController.php on line
>   191 and defined

PAYPALCONTROLLER.php

```
<?php

namespace dixard\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use dixard\Http\Requests;
use dixard\Http\Controllers\Controller;




use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;





use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

use dixard\Order;
use dixard\OrderItem;

class PaypalController extends BaseController
{
    private $_api_context; //conterrà tutte config

    public function __construct()
    {
        // setup PayPal api context
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }

    //

    public function postPayment(Request $request)
    {
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $items = array();
        $subtotal = 0;
        $cart = \Session::get('cart'); //ottenere tutta l'informazione dalla session cart
        $currency = 'EUR';

        $cell = $request->get('phone_ship');

        //return $cell;

        // impostiamo tutte le informazioni  
        foreach($cart as $producto){
            $item = new Item();
            $item->setName($producto->name)
            ->setCurrency($currency)
            ->setDescription($producto->extract)
            ->setQuantity($producto->quantity)
            ->setPrice($producto->price);

            $items[] = $item;
            $subtotal += $producto->quantity * $producto->price;
        }

        ////
        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems($items);
        // //
        $details = new Details();
        $details->setSubtotal($subtotal)
        ->setShipping(1);

        ////

        $total = $subtotal + 1;

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency($currency)
            ->setTotal($total)
            ->setDetails($details);

        // creiamo oggetto transaction e passiamo l'imposrto

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($item_list)
            ->setDescription('order Laravel App Store');


        // Redirect //
        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(\URL::route('payment.status'))
            ->setCancelUrl(\URL::route('payment.status'));

        // ///

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        //controll api /

        try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
        } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
            if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
                echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
                $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true);
                exit;
            } else {
                die('Ups! error');
            }
        }

        // URL approval

        foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }

        // add payment ID to session, //
        \Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

        // //

        if(isset($redirect_url)) {
            // redirect to paypal
            return \Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }

        // 
        return \Redirect::route('cart-show')
            ->with('message', 'Ups! Error.');




    }







    public function getPaymentStatus()
    {
        // Get the payment ID before session clear
        $payment_id = \Session::get('paypal_payment_id');

        // clear the session payment ID
        \Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');

        $payerId = \Input::get('PayerID');
        $token = \Input::get('token');

        if (empty($payerId) || empty($token)) {
            return \Redirect('products')
                ->with('message', 'Error with payment');
        }

        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);

        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId(\Input::get('PayerID'));

        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);


        if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {

            $this->saveOrder(); // quindi richiamo metodo saveOrder e salviamo tutto
            // completat order

            \Session::forget('cart');

            return \Redirect('orderComplete')
                ->with('message', 'Order complete! good!');
        }
        return \Redirect('orderComplete')
            ->with('message-error', 'Payment cancelled');
    }

    protected function saveOrder(Request $Request)
    {
        $subtotal = 0;
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $shipping = 1;




        foreach($cart as $producto){
            $subtotal += $producto->quantity * $producto->price;

        }



        $order = Order::create([
            'subtotal' => $subtotal,
            'shipping' => $shipping,
            'phone_ship' => $request->get('phone_ship') ,

            //'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id
        ]);

        foreach($cart as $producto){
            $this->saveOrderItem($producto, $order->id);
        }
    }

    protected function saveOrderItem($producto, $order_id)
    {
        OrderItem::create([
            'price' => $producto->price,
            'quantity' => $producto->quantity,
            'product_id' => $producto->id,
            'order_id' => $order_id
        ]);
    }
}
```

ORDER-DETAIL.PHP

```
<form class="login" method="post" action="{{url('payment')}}">

 {{csrf_field()}}
<!--<form action="checkout.html" method="POST" >-->
    <div class="checkout-wrapper">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="text-alert">
                <p>Returning customer? <a href="#">Click here to login</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.text-alert -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2>Fatturazione</h2>


                    <fieldset id="billinfo">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="first_name_shipping">Nome <sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dark" id="first_name_shipping" placeholder="Nome" >
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="last_name_shipping">Cognome <sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dark" id="last_name_shipping" placeholder="Cognome">
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="address_shipping">Indirizzo <sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dark" id="address_shipping" placeholder="Via/Piazza/Viale" >
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="address2_shipping">Interno/Scala <sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dark" id="address2_shipping" placeholder="ScalaA/Interno:11" >
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="province_shipping">Provincia<sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dark" id="province_shipping" placeholder="Roma,Milano,ecc" >
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="country_shipping">Paese<sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dark" id="country_shipping" placeholder="Paese" value="" >
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email_shipping">Email<sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dark" id="email_shipping" placeholder="Email" value="{{Auth::user()->email}}" >
                          </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phone_shipping">Cellulare<sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dark" id="phone_ship" placeholder="Telefono/Cellulare" name="phone_ship" >
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </fieldset>
</form>
```

ROUTES.PHP

//paypal routes

```
Route::post('payment', array(
    'as' => 'payment',
    'uses' => 'PaypalController@postPayment',

));


Route::get('payment', array(
    'as' => 'payment',
    'uses' => 'PaypalController@getPayment',
));

//Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
//Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');



//paypal redirect alla nostra route

Route::get('payment/status', array(
    'as' => 'payment.status',
    'uses' => 'PaypalController@getPaymentStatus',
));

// Pagine ordine completato

Route::get('orderComplete','CartController@orderComplete');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not pass `Request` object. Add this to `getPaymentStatus()`:

```
public function getPaymentStatus(Request $request)
{
```

And then use `saveOrder()` like this:

```
$this->saveOrder($request);
```

Comment: Yes i done  so, But now i have this error, SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'fullname_ship' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `orders` (`subtotal`, `shipping`, `fullname_ship`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (10, 1, , 2016-05-09 15:39:40, 2016-05-09 15:39:40))  |  I idded name="fullname_ship" id="fullname_ship" on my field FULL NAME SHIPPING, About My model is :                              class Order extends Model
{
    
 
 protected $table = 'orders';
 
 
 
 protected $fillable = [
 
 'subtotal',
 'shipping',
 'fullname_ship',
 
 
 
 
 ];
}

Comment: @Diego182, this error is not related to your original question. You should ask new question and post relevant data there (like your models, relations and appropriate code).

Comment: Yes i added a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117747/laravel-5-error-storage-form-data  Thank you very much for your help!